# Where can you see the progress in terminal when updating homebrew?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

My terminal said

```
Updating Homebrew...
```

Then i had to wait an didn't know what was going on.
Is there a way to see the progress somewhere in terminal? Like a bar going from 0% to 100%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command

```
brew update --verbose
```